# Typeahead.js 0.10.x: how to show number of results per category

Tags: typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

Typeahead.js 0.10 supports templates for header and footer as well as for search results. I would like to be able to get the real number of results/suggestions for each category (i.e ignoring the limit value) and display this in the category name header.

for example -

RESULTS:

- Category A **(24 Results)**

  - -A1
  - -A2
  - -A3
- Category B **(167 Results)**

  - -B1
  - -B2
  - -B3

My template currently looks something like this:

```
{
name: 'Applications',
displayKey: 'value',
source: app.ttAdapter(),
extraVars:Handlebars.registerHelper("numResults",function(){
    return (  "HowToGetTheseResults??" );
}),
templates: {
    header:Handlebars.compile([
        '<h3 class="applications"> Applications ({{numResults}}) results  </h3>'
    ].join('')),

    suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
        '<p><b>{{value}}</b> </p>'
    ].join(''))
}
```

Is there an easy way to get type-ahead to return me the number of results/suggestions? I'm sure the typeahead object (or the bloodhound object?) must store this data somewhere.

Comment: It's not possible as of v0.10.2, but it's something that will probably [be addressed in a future release](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/757).

Answer (score 6):

You can define your own function that processes the query entered by the user.

I made a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dtengeri/6ApJg/

The basic idea is that you get the suggestions from the Bloodhound engine manually and only pass the required amount of results to typeahead.

```
// Custom source function in the dataset definition.
source: function (query, cb) { 
  // Get the data from the Blodhound engine and process it.
  nbaTeams.get(query, function (suggestions) {
    // Show only the first 3 results.
    cb(suggestions.slice(0, 3));
    // Set the headers content.
    $('#nba-header').text(suggestions.length);
  })
},
```

You have to define an HTML element inside the header template where you will put the number of results. (The span with the id #nba-header in this example.)

```
templates: {
  // Insert an HTML element where you will place the number of results.
  header: '<h3 class="league-name">NBA Teams (<span id="nba-header"></span>)</h3>'
}
```

In order to get all results you should set a high number as a limit in the Bloodhound engine:

```
var nbaTeams = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: nba(),
  limit: Number.MAX_VALUE // Set the limit as high as possible.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Came here and found this answer to be helpful. Here's another way of doing it which will keep a title at the top of each section, and add a count.

var initTypeahead = function(){

```
// Sets where the data is coming from
var nbaTeams = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../Scripts/vendor/typeahead.js/example_data/nba.json'
});

var nhlTeams = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../Scripts/vendor/typeahead.js/example_data/nba.json'
});

// Finds the input and inits Typeahead
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},

// Defines how suggestions are displayed
{
  name: 'nba-teams',
  display: 'team',
  source: nbaTeams,
  templates: {

    header: function (context) {
        // calculate total hits here
        return '<h3 class="group-name">NBA Teams: ' + context.suggestions.length + '</h3>';
    }
  }
},
{
  name: 'nhl-teams',
  display: 'team',
  source: nhlTeams,
  templates: {
    header: function (context) {
        // calculate total hits here
        return '<h3 class="group-name">NHL Teams: ' + context.suggestions.length + '</h3>';
    }     }
});
```

}